VS Code "Explorer" search not finding folder names
I'm back on, what is VS code doing?
As of today, Oct, 4th, 2024 My vs code updated like an hour ago of posting this; the Explorer search function stopped working. I had previously posted a somewhat similar issue 3 months back. My issue back then was that when I pressed ctrl + f the search bar only showed in the editor and not in the explorer. My VS code pops out the search bar on the explorer when I press ctrl + f, so it's not the keyboard bindings as my issue from last time.
Now when I search for anything using the Search bar in the "explorer", all my folders in my explorer just disappear as if the search doesn't find anything. The "search" works if I just manually type the name of the folder in the explorer(not using the search bar). It is easer to just copy paste the name of the folder for the website I am working on so the search bar feature is somewhat important to me.
Anyone know if there's any settings change I need to make to fix this?


I've tried searching a bit on keyboard bindings to see if there's anything I can change and test, and also made some changes to my settings to anything pertaining to "explorer", "search", "find", "filter" but could not find anything that fixes the issue, Maybe I missed something.
I did test to see if the "editor" search was affected as well but everything works fine there.
I also tried the search on my personal projects folder since it consists of a much smaller stack of folders and when I tried search for a folder it did not load anything and the explorer showed blank but when I tried searching for a file, it seems to be searching for files but not folders, maybe this info can be of help?

I did try to search for files in my work folder but it's showing nothing, as the second Image I posted; Maybe it's just taking too long since there's a lot of folders it's sifting through; Still, this is not ideal.
Update:
It seem this issue was cause by the latest VS-Code update. A lot of people seem to be experiencing similar issues and the VS-Code team is looking into it. I downgraded to the previous v1.93 for the time being

I believe this new Explorer search only finds files, not folders.  Is that your issue?

Hey mark, yes that's correct. The the new explorer search doesn't seem to find folders any more

It seem this issue was cause by the latest VS-Code update. The VS code team mentioned that they will be working on improving this in the following 2 months.
Github thread for reference: github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/230714

The ability to find folders/directories in the Explorer has been added to vscode. It is in the Insiders Build as of today.  Should be in Stable early December 2024.
Support finding folders int explorer find
Explorer Find: Support finding folders
I tested this today and it does filter by both folders and files now.

I don't think it's exist anymore, but you can do is to focus on one of the files and press f3, this will let you search in the list of files and folders.
Note that it will let you search just in what is visible in the list, if you want to look for folders in folder you need to expand them all.
Edit:
list.find is the one


I've tried f3 and it doesn't work for folders unfortunately. Not sure why vs code seems to have removed this feature as it's somewhat important. Especially when working in a workspace.

editing with a pic

Yup, that's the first place I checked but unfortunately that's not the issue. My key binding is good. It's the search bar that doesn't seem to function as it did anymore. I'll ask on their github to see if I can get anything from them.
